# Android : determine zoom level from circle

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-play-services

I am using this code for determining zoom level from circle , but it's not returning valid zoom level,what is the problem?
I want to set map zoom level for display all part of circle.

```
public float getZoomLevel(Circle circle) 
{
    float zoomLevel = 11;
    if (circle != null) {
        double radius = circle.getRadius() + circle.getRadius() / 2;
        double scale = radius / 500;
        zoomLevel = (float) (16 - Math.log(scale) / Math.log(2));
    }
    return zoomLevel;
}
```

Comment: If you want to fit your circle into the map, you can try this method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17278527/4195406

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it with `Math.floor` and using integer instead of float

```
public int getZoomLevel(Circle circle) 
{
    int zoomLevel = 11;
    if (circle != null) 
    {
        double radius = circle.getRadius();
        double scale = radius / 500;
        zoomLevel = (int) Math.floor((16 - Math.log(scale) / Math.log(2)));
    }
    return zoomLevel ;
}
```

Comment: any idea what the 500 scale factor stands for ? how did you find that ?