# Zoom in on bouns route obtained from Google Maps v2 android

Tags: android

I need an explanation of how to work with CameraUpdateFactory. My app draws a route on the screen and I need to centralize this route map. Then get the bounds of the route and try to set the zoom.
But when I run the huge zoom, referring to the documentation says CameraUpdateFactory of the highest zoom possible but that's not what I need.

```
         mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
              mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 6));               
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adjusting google map (api v2) zoom level in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220404/adjusting-google-map-api-v2-zoom-level-in-android?rq=1)

It works!

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fromPosition).title(start_address));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(toPosition).title(end_address));

    com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds.Builder boundsBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
    boundsBuilder.include(fromPosition);
    boundsBuilder.include(toPosition);              

    final LatLngBounds bounds = boundsBuilder.build();

    mMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onMapLoaded() {
              mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 12));              
            }
        });
```